# Vbox/Vagrant cannot start virtual machine and I cannot open a console

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have installed latest version of Vagrant and VirtualBox in a Windows Desktop. After do some changes in a linux virtual machine I ran

```
vagrant halt

vagrant up
```

then the problem appears. The vm has some trouble, I can see it by the preview of VirtualBox Administrator but I don't know how to open console (like you do in Vmware) to fix the problem.

At the end vagrant gets a timeout but this problem makes that the other vm of the Vagrantfile will also won't boot.

Is there any way to open a console in VBox to fix this kind of problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Won't help with already started VM, but you can enable the VirtualBox GUI in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

Comment: This is my best trick for troubleshooting startup problems (usual symptom: timeout while trying to SSH). When starting in GUI mode you'll learn whether something at boot time is stuck or prompting for input. (E.g. grub boot loader.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, `vagrant ssh` ?
This will open a SSH connection to your VM.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do a $vagrant ssh or simply open a ssh with putty because virtual machine has any kind of trouble, I can see it by the preview console so obviously, linux is not able to start the init process and start ssh daemon. VM is stucked with a kind of menu and I can not do anything.

Comment: Sorry then... I don't know.